# SQLite Select whichever column is greater

Tags: sqlite

I'm really a novice at SQLite, so thanks in advance for any help.

I have a table with two timestamp columns, one is a start time and the other is an end time. I want to select the which ever column is greater for each row. (end time is zero for unfinished tasks)

I think I need to use a [CASE](http://www.sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html) expression but I just can't figure this one out.

Here is a select statement I tried that threw an exception, but shows what I'm going for.

```
SELECT _id, vin, command_id, CASE WHEN end_timestamp  >= start_timestamp THEN end_timestamp ELSE start_timestamp, status 
FROM reflash_commands ORDER BY start_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Try adding 'END' after 'ELSE start_timestamp' - does that make it work?

Comment: @LeopoldStotch Thank You, that fixed it! I'm surprised I was so close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `END` keyword. Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
_id, 
vin, 
command_id, 
CASE WHEN end_timestamp  >= start_timestamp 
THEN end_timestamp 
ELSE start_timestamp END, 
status 
FROM reflash_commands ORDER BY start_timestamp DESC
```